# Idiomatic C# for object only interacting though having registered to events

Tags: c#, events, constructor, garbage-collection

I am uneasy about the way I have designed a simple program.
There is a `FileParser` object which has `OnFileOpened`, `OnLineParsed`, and `OnFileClosed` events, and several objects which create smaller files based on the content of the file which the `FileParser` parses.

The objects observing the `FileParser` register their methods with the `FileParser` events in their constructors.

```
ParsedFileFrobber(FileParser fileParser)
{
    fileParser.OnFileOpen += this.OpenNewFrobFile;
    fileParser.OnLineParsed += this.WriteFrobbedLine;
    fileParser.OnFileClose += this.CloseFrobFile;
}
```

After that, the `ParsedFileFrobber` just gets on with things without further explicit interaction.

The thing that bothers me is that the main program only ever assigns a `ParsedFileFrobber` and basically doesn't use the return value of the constructor, so to say.

```
var fileParser = new FileParser(myFilename);
var parsedFileFrobber = new ParsedFileFrobber(fileParser);
// No further mentions of parsedFileFrobber.
```

It works, but ReSharper complains about this, which at least makes me pause to think. Actually, I don't even need to assign a variable to the result of the constructor, as the GC will keep the `ParsedFileFrobber` alive by merit of the event handler references, but a bare `new` looks very wrong to me. (It still compiles and runs correctly.)

```
var fileParser = new FileParser(myFilename);
new ParsedFileFrobber(fileParser);
```

Is this a problem? Is it an anti-pattern or a code smell? Is there already an idiomatic way of doing this in C#?

Thanks!

Clarifications thanks to helpful comments:

1) Why not invert the relationship? Cody Gray

Ah, the example was a bit too simplified. I actually have a `ParsedFileFrobber`, a `ParsedFileGrobber`, and a `ParsedFileBrobber`. Inverting the relationship would make the `FileParser` dependent on all 3. (Also, initially there was only a Frobber and a Grobber, but later on there was a need for a Brobber, and there is still scope for uh, a Drobber and so forth.) I guess that it's a matter of taste about whether the lines of code doing the subscription happen in the `FileParser` constructor or in the `ParsedFileFrobber`, `ParsedFileGrobber`, and `ParsedFileBrobber` constructors, but my preference is to try to keep the `FileParser` as agnostic as possible.

2) Why not move the constructor into a static method (and make the constructor private)? Hans Passant

I can see how that tidies away the possibly-unintuitive usage into the private inner workings of the class, which is good advice. However, it would still be either the bare `new` or the only-ever-assigned reference to the return value of the constructor. Well, if it's not a big problem, it makes sense to hide away the ugly code. (For reference, I did make the `ParsedFileFrobber` an `IDisposable` with the `Dispose` method unsubscribing from the events, so it is possible to put an end to the frobbing.)

Thank you to all commenters!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that I understand the design, but my first question would be, why not invert the relationship? Currently, you have ParsedFileFrobber depend upon FileParser, but then never use the instance of ParsedFileFrobber again. Why not instead make FileParser depend upon ParsedFileFrobber, since you're (apparently) keeping a reference to the FileParser object anyway?

Comment: Not that much to fret about, just a good reminder that it is going to frob forever as long as the FileParser object stays alive.  You can make it look "natural" by adding a static method to ParseFileFrobber.  Name it, erm, Frob() or Observe().  Make the constructor private.

Comment: I'm wondering why you are not going to need the created `ParsedFileFrobber` instance. Obviously that class (and its relatives `ParsedFile*`) are doing something in the event handlers producing a certain state. Where is that state kept? From what we know, that must be inside the `ParsedFileFrobber`. And if we are interested in that state (I guess we are, otherwise, why would we parse the file after all), we would also need to access the instance of the `ParsedFileFrobber`. Seems to me we're seeing only part of the picture and not the entire thing here.

Comment: "Inverting the relationship would make the FileParser dependent on all 3." – not necessarily so if you use a common interface for the ParsedFile* classes.

Comment: @Dirk Vollmar The `ParsedFileFrobber` writes a file with frobbed results. That's where its state ends up, so to speak. We're not interested in the state during the execution of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with something like what Hans Passant recommended: tidying away the bare new into the inner workings of a static method.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution could be to use the [Mediator pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/mediator-design-pattern), which introduces a new class who controls the interaction between your `FileParser` and the `ParsedFile*` classes:. That way your classes are very loosely coupled, your `FileParser` does not need to know about the `ParsedFileFrobber` and vice versa. The mediator class can also take care of the lifetime of the objects.

```
public interface IParsedFile
{
    void OnOpen();
    void OnLineParsed(string line);
    void OnClosed();
}

public class FileParseManager
{
    private readonly FileParser _fileParser;
    private readonly List<IParsedFile> _parsedFiles;

    public FileParseManager(FileParser fileParser, List<IParsedFile> parsedFiles)
    {
        _fileParser = fileParser;
        _parsedFiles = parsedFiles;
    }

    public void Parse(string fileName)
    {
        _fileParser.OpenFile(string fileName);
        foreach (var parsedFile in _parsedFiles)
        {
            parsedFile.OnOpen();
        }

        while ((string line = _fileParser.GetNextLine()) != null)
        {
            foreach (var parsedFile in _parsedFiles)
            {
                parsedFile.OnLineParsed(line);
            }
        }

        _fileParser.CloseFile();
        foreach (var parsedFile in _parsedFiles)
        {
            parsedFile.OnClosed();
        }
    }
}
```

Another option might be to use a **producer-consumer** pattern. Something like this is provided e.g. by the TPL (Task Parallel Library) in the .NET Framework. Have a look at the [Dataflow section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx) and the examples provided there.

Comment: I appreciate the references, but this does seem to be reproducing the effect of the event-handler system explicitly without any obvious advantage, especially since it is not necessary for the Grobber to have an OnOpen() for example, whereas here it would have to be implemented (as a no-op).